# Error to add local sql database with MS Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, local-database

I installed all Visual Studio 2015, SQL express 2014, and SQL Manager 2014. When I try to add new .mdf database by click [add new item] under [Project] in Visual Studio, it will pops up a message like the picture[image]

However, when I try to create a local database by right click [add connections] in [Server Explore] section, it also pops up a message like the picture[image]

In addition, my local sever configuration is like this
[image]

How can solve this problem. What am going to do is try to add local database to my application, so after I publish my application this database will store the information for user.

Comment: Adding a connection implies your database already exists. See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Problem solved, I re-installed SqlLocalDB. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I re-installed SqlLocalDB.